Merge sorting algorithm works for small list but crashes with bigger ones
I'm trying to recreate the merge sorting algorithm and while my code works for lists with length 4 or less
when the length gets bigger it crushes.
As you'll see the error says that on some point sorted_right becomes NoneType.
I tried debugging it but couldn't understand why this happens.
Can anyone help me with this?
My code:
my_list = [5, 35, 10, 1, 0]

def merge_sort(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    elif len(array) == 2:
        if array[0] > array[1]:
            array[0], array[1] = array[1], array[0]
        return array
    else:
        sorted_part = []
        left = array[:len(array)//2]
        right = array[len(array)//2:]
        sorted_left = merge_sort(left)
        sorted_right = merge_sort(right)
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if len(sorted_left) == 0:
                sorted_part.extend(sorted_right)
                break
            elif len(sorted_right) == 0:
                sorted_part.extend(sorted_left)
                break
            else:
                if sorted_left[0] < sorted_right[0]:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_left.pop(0))
                else:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_right.pop(0))
    print(sorted_part)


merge_sort(my_list)

The error:
[0, 1, 10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Mathima 15\askisis 10 merge sort.py", line 32, in <module>
    merge_sort(my_list)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Mathima 15\askisis 10 merge sort.py", line 21, in merge_sort
    elif len(sorted_right) == 0:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1


If you don't understand why it happens, then it's time to debug your code: find the smallest list for which things go wrong, and start logging what happens at each important decision making point in your code. For instance, start logging input length at the start of merge_sort, as well as which of your three conditional blocks you end up in as a result.

You don't have a return for when the array is longer than 2 elements, so you're returning None

I think you meant "crashes" not "crushes".

If you're going to use the return value from a recursive function in the function, it needs to return in every scenario. Your else branch has no such return. The solution is simple: return sorted_part.
def merge_sort(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return array
    elif len(array) == 2:
        if array[0] > array[1]:
            array[0], array[1] = array[1], array[0]
        return array
    else:
        sorted_part = []
        left = array[:len(array)//2]
        right = array[len(array)//2:]
        sorted_left = merge_sort(left)
        sorted_right = merge_sort(right)
        for i in range(len(array)):
            if len(sorted_left) == 0:
                sorted_part.extend(sorted_right)
                break
            elif len(sorted_right) == 0:
                sorted_part.extend(sorted_left)
                break
            else:
                if sorted_left[0] < sorted_right[0]:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_left.pop(0))
                else:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_right.pop(0))
        return sorted_part

The print at the end of the function is extraneous now as it would never be reached.
This also seems like a good place to apply the match/case syntax introduced in Python 3.10.
def merge_sort(array):
    match array:
        case [_]: return array
        case [a, b] if a < b: return array
        case [a, b]: return [b, a]
        case _:
            sorted_part = []
            left = array[:len(array)//2]
            right = array[len(array)//2:]
            sorted_left = merge_sort(left)
            sorted_right = merge_sort(right)
            for i in range(len(array)):
                if len(sorted_left) == 0:
                    sorted_part.extend(sorted_right)
                    break
                elif len(sorted_right) == 0:
                    sorted_part.extend(sorted_left)
                    break
                elif sorted_left[0] < sorted_right[0]:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_left.pop(0))
                else:
                    sorted_part.append(sorted_right.pop(0))
            return sorted_part

As a sidenote: array is a potentially misleading name for a list.
You may also wish to return a new list in the simpler cases.
        case [_]: return list(array)
        case [a, b] if a < b: return list(array)


I'd also advise against returning array. Safer to be consistent and always return a new list.
